# Microsoft Excel and Word show gray boxes on switching window. How to get rid of these?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, display, microsoft-office

Recently, whenever I switch windows in Microsoft Excel or Words, I see these random gray boxes which disappear as soon as I take my mouse cursor over them.

What's the solution to get rid of these permanently?

See my attaching a screenshot for reference below:

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Try Disabling Hardware Acceleration in Excel. File--> Options --> Advanced --> Display --> Disable Hardware Acceleration and recheck.You may have to restart Office for changes to be in effect.

Comment: Wow this worked! Thanks a lot for helping out. You can put this as an answer, if that will be helpful for you when I close this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting Office 2007 (I guess) MS Office has introduced Graphics Hardware Acceleration feature. However on some hardware it may not work the best. In case you are getting issues like the contents inside the Excel sheet do not appear sharper or have issued as described in the above question or even in case while moving to the next cell Excel momentarily freezes, it's best to disable this feature.

When you install MS Office, this option is enabled by default.

In order to disable this option go to MS Excel --> 
File--> Options --> Advanced --> Display --> Disable Hardware Graphics Acceleration

It's a toggle switch. Tick it to disable the same.

You may have to restart Office for changes to take effect.

As reported by this user, disabling this settings solved the issue.

[image]